# Easy way to render TileMill tiles in retina mode with Leaflet?

Tags: leaflet, tilemill, scale-factor, retina

I have a few quick little map websites that run straight off TileMill, without pre-exporting. They usually have code like this:

```
L.tileLayer('http://example.com:20008/tile/MyMap/{z}/{x}/{y}.png',
  {}).addTo(map);
```

How do you make this take advantage of a Retina type high resolution display, without just making everything (especially text!) tiny?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turns out to be really simple, because TileMill supports scaling features.

```
L.tileLayer('http://example.com:20008/tile/MyMap/{z}/{x}/{y}.png'
    + (L.Browser.retina ? '&scale=2': ''), 
    {  detectRetina:true
    }).addTo(i);
```

There are three parts:

1. `L.Browser.retina` tells you there is a retina display, which you use to...
2. request scaled map tiles from Tilemill with `&scale=2`, which...
3. Leaflet renders physically smaller with `detectRetina:true`

Similar logic would be used for pre-exported tiles. You'd export two sets, one at scale=2, and then point Leaflet at whichever is appropriate.

It looks like `mapbox.js` [used to have a special option for this](https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox.js/api/v1.6.0/retina/).

Answer (score 1):

I found this question when I tried to find out how to get retina working with vanilla Leaflet and Mapbox. If others end on the same trail, this is how I made it work:

```
var url = 'https://api.mapbox.com/v4/mapbox.streets/{z}/{x}/{y}';
    url += (L.Browser.retina ? '@2x.png' : '.png');
    url += '?access_token=my-token';
```

No need to use `detectRetina`!

This is basically [what mapbox.js does internally](https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox.js/blob/538d229ab6767bb4c3f3969c417f9884189c1512/src/tile_layer.js#L21)

Comment: Maybe `detectRetina: true` is the default now. Previously, if you didn't set it, you'd just end up with double-sized tiles.

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for: a way to use raster Mapbox tiles in a mobile-friendly Leaflet map.